# Does MySQL have a special role named PUBLIC like SQL Server or Oracle?

Tags: mysql, sql

Does MySQL have a special role named PUBLIC like SQL Server or Oracle?

[image: Introduction of PUBLIC in sql server]

Comment: Are you want to create a user who has access to all databases?

Comment: @M.HamzaRajput  Thanks for help. I just want to grant privileges to PUBLIC, but it failed in MySQL.

Comment: Every DBMS has its own implementation of features. Please tell me what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: What I typed was "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO PUBLIC". I want to know whether PUBLIC is supported in MySQL and if not, is there any way to replace it.

Comment: Have you checked the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MySQL-8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/roles.html) and [MariaDB-10.0+](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/roles_overview/) have roles.

In both cases no roles exist by default, however its easy to create them and grant privileges to the role.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a small workaround.**

```
CREATE ROLE 'app_developer';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'app_developer';
CREATE USER 'dev1'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'dev1pass';
GRANT 'app_developer' TO 'dev1'@'%';
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'dev1'@'%';
```

**Now dev1 has all the access of entire databases even from a remote connection.**

Comment: You may need `SET DEFAULT ROLE`. Note: flush privileges never needed for user modification, only after (the hopefully never needed again) direct table modifications of mysql tables.